# Magento - Saving data in to order during adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data event

Tags: events, magento

I have an observer set up on "adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data".

I have added a new form field (custom attribute added) to the admin create order form:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml
```

And then in my observer I capture that field like so:

```
$orderRequest = $data->getEvent()->getRequest('order');
$customField = $orderRequest['customfield'];
```

I need to store in my db the customField and the orderId (but of course at the point my observer is called the order hasn't been created so I can't get any id)

Ideally I want to be able to save the data in the quote/order object using setData() and then set up another observer once the quote/order gets saved and save it against the order there but at this point there is no quote or order object available!

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't clearly understood your question, but what might make sense for you:

1. Every order makes reservation for incrementId(orderId?).
2. Every order has it's own protect code.
3. For order save there should be something like sales_order_save_after and sales_order_save_before events.

**UPDATE 1**

Well all in all currently i see one solution:

From

```
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data
```

you should get

```
$observer->getOrderCreateModel()
```

Which has method

```
$model->getQuote()
```

Quote has

```
$quote->getReservedOrderId()
```

WHich should return you order_id.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use sales_order_place_before/after because those events do not have access to the request parameters. (or at least I can't see a way to get it?). How would I get the orderId from within adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data?

Comment: Ahh that is a good point! Yes it does get what I need. I will do some quick tests and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Your first comment regarding Mage::app()->getRequest() was what I was missing and now it is working perfectly! Thanks for your help.